# Yield to Maturity using BrentSolver

Tags: java, finance, apache-commons, yield

I have this error when calculating the yield to maturity of coupon based bonds, I have all the templates that I need and tested them, no problem in there, but when I tried to run it gave me an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NoBracketingException: function values at endpoints do not have different signs, endpoints: [0, 0.9], values: [4.5, 19.138]
> at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BrentSolver.doSolve(BrentSolver.java:132)
> at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:199)
> at Pack1.YTM.calculateYTM(YTM.java:54)
> at Pack1.YTM.calculateYTMForAllSeries(YTM.java:60)
> at Pack1.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:21)

Tried to change bounds and initialGuess but it still don't work, does it have any logic issue that I missed?

```
UnivariateFunction function = new UnivariateFunction() {
            @Override
            public double value(double r) {
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (double j = 1; j <= maturity * frequency; j++) {
                    sum += (CouponPayment / frequency) / Math.pow(1 + r / frequency, j);
                }
                sum += FaceValue / Math.pow(1 + r / frequency, maturity * frequency);
                return Price - sum;
            }
        };
        
        UnivariateSolver solver = new BrentSolver();
        double lowerBound = 0.0; // Lower bound
        double upperBound = 0.9; // Upper bound
        double initialGuess = 0.01; // Initial guess

        double ytm = solver.solve(1000, function, lowerBound, upperBound, initialGuess);
        return ytm; // yield
    }
```